# Error while broadcasting the raw bitcoin testnet transaction

Tags: transactions, signature, testnet, broadcast

I am trying to create a simple P2PKH raw bitcoin testnet transaction from the scratch. Here is the information about the transaction:

```
hash of the UTXO consumed - 03e3f89f38ea81a5f1ed277e6ac424cebde4426f4bcc291006f7ecf67350e986
index of the UTXO - 1
private key of the input - 4b5963fc219d1848cc67d52e0a929340f88ff9d316b1990b24d0ae1d37edeef1 
UTXO amount - 0.01 tBTC
receiving address - mtCrEgpKyRhLguqGySE4qUFXzn8sMG7hrm
receiving amount - 0.001 tBTC
change Address - mjHQ5W5B14psNsYBEmh1BykXyY4sY9r9DF
fees used - 378 sats
change amount - 0.00899622 tBTC
```

Here is the unsigned raw transaction I created:

```
010000000186e95073f6ecf7061029cc4b6f42e4bdce24c46a7e27edf1a581ea389ff8e303010000001976a914d4dc68f4d94196536c0726f51a91d500c7afa60888acffffffff0226ba0d00000000001976a914295033e5bfe3e8734334addc62c82d9c6eab981388aca0860100000000001976a9148b2d174384a41deeb78e012f4582e29b6e0d161588ac0000000001000000
```

Double SHA-256 digest of the above to be signed:

```
4b5963fc219d1848cc67d52e0a929340f88ff9d316b1990b24d0ae1d37edeef1
```

Next I am using self-written ECDSA library to sign the transaction. I have signed the above transaction using my library three times.

Signed Transaction 1:

```
010000000186e95073f6ecf7061029cc4b6f42e4bdce24c46a7e27edf1a581ea389ff8e303010000006b483045022100a482537e4225c1ba3470c68d2304d807a6e245491b486e1c6d0778a8436d25dd0220cf4cc90f2e41cafca39555caeb47be235b9c10c2b497528532cb419a7736a8d1012103ab127bf811fd8a6753fbc8cd68731a120d05ac64f1e03df5ec223d7a734e6199ffffffff0226ba0d00000000001976a914295033e5bfe3e8734334addc62c82d9c6eab981388aca0860100000000001976a9148b2d174384a41deeb78e012f4582e29b6e0d161588ac00000000

Signature: 3045022100a482537e4225c1ba3470c68d2304d807a6e245491b486e1c6d0778a8436d25dd0220cf4cc90f2e41cafca39555caeb47be235b9c10c2b497528532cb419a7736a8d1012103ab127bf811fd8a6753fbc8cd68731a120d05ac64f1e03df5ec223d7a734e6199

R: a482537e4225c1ba3470c68d2304d807a6e245491b486e1c6d0778a8436d25dd
S: cf4cc90f2e41cafca39555caeb47be235b9c10c2b497528532cb419a7736a8d1
```

Signed Transaction 2:

```
010000000186e95073f6ecf7061029cc4b6f42e4bdce24c46a7e27edf1a581ea389ff8e303010000006b48304502210076a3092727f537453e938a07c9558c605bb79824972b50386e909d8b0394f9700220745b9869b1a4e7b4671a538b7f015a19567250a66f7e965af09060450fdf4288012103ab127bf811fd8a6753fbc8cd68731a120d05ac64f1e03df5ec223d7a734e6199ffffffff0226ba0d00000000001976a914295033e5bfe3e8734334addc62c82d9c6eab981388aca0860100000000001976a9148b2d174384a41deeb78e012f4582e29b6e0d161588ac00000000

Signature: 304502210076a3092727f537453e938a07c9558c605bb79824972b50386e909d8b0394f9700220745b9869b1a4e7b4671a538b7f015a19567250a66f7e965af09060450fdf4288012103ab127bf811fd8a6753fbc8cd68731a120d05ac64f1e03df5ec223d7a734e6199

R: 76a3092727f537453e938a07c9558c605bb79824972b50386e909d8b0394f970
S: 745b9869b1a4e7b4671a538b7f015a19567250a66f7e965af09060450fdf4288
```

Signed Transaction 3:

```
010000000186e95073f6ecf7061029cc4b6f42e4bdce24c46a7e27edf1a581ea389ff8e303010000006b4830450221009b6cf3115f5738998b249cafecd69bc489b770cb104a885f93f000df662ca9860220459c6548f4a5b8032529069d704857b92ff3693684be401430a7ca6b2c28e66d012103ab127bf811fd8a6753fbc8cd68731a120d05ac64f1e03df5ec223d7a734e6199ffffffff0226ba0d00000000001976a914295033e5bfe3e8734334addc62c82d9c6eab981388aca0860100000000001976a9148b2d174384a41deeb78e012f4582e29b6e0d161588ac00000000

Signature: 30450221009b6cf3115f5738998b249cafecd69bc489b770cb104a885f93f000df662ca9860220459c6548f4a5b8032529069d704857b92ff3693684be401430a7ca6b2c28e66d012103ab127bf811fd8a6753fbc8cd68731a120d05ac64f1e03df5ec223d7a734e6199

R: 9b6cf3115f5738998b249cafecd69bc489b770cb104a885f93f000df662ca986
S: 459c6548f4a5b8032529069d704857b92ff3693684be401430a7ca6b2c28e66d
```

I used [Blockstream Broadcasting](https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/push) tool to push my transaction. However, signed transaction 1 and 2 failed with the following error:

```
sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-26,"message":"non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Non-canonical DER signature)"}
```

Finally, signed transaction 3 went successfully and [confirmed on the blockchain](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/c34dbf96a6546e2992db78a5a5bc18eeb529d995be799424a41d0334ee81521d/). I have verified all three signatures and there is nothing wrong in ECDSA params R and S. So, in my view the problem locates in the DER-encoding of the signature. Help me locate the problem about why do the sig-script verification failed for the first two transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few rules regarding the DER signature that you are not following. In the first transaction, you fail to follow the Low-S value rule. In the second transaction, you fail to follow the strict DER encoding rule.

In the first transaction, the `s` value is too high. Current standardness rules require that the `s` be between `0x1` and `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5D576E7357A4501DDFE92F46681B20A0` inclusive. Your `s` is out of this range. To convert a high `s` to a low `s`, you do `s' = n - s` where `n` is the order of the secp256k1 curve, i.e. `n = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141`.

In the second transaction, your signature does not follow the strict DER encoding rules. These rules are defined in [BIP 66](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0066.mediawiki). Specifically, the `r` is encoded using 33 bytes when only 32 bytes is sufficient. The `0x00` that you have prepended is unnecessary in this case because `r` as a 32 byte signed integer is positive. That prepended `0x00` is only necessary when `r` as a 32 byte signed integer would be a negative number, i.e. the top bit is set.

In your third transaction, you got lucky. Because you are using a random nonce, half of the time `s` will be low, and half of the time `r` as a 32 byte integer will be negative and require the prepended `0x00` to become positive. So 1 in 4 signatures should be accepted, and that's basically what we see here.

Related to the error in the second transaction, on thing you need to watch out for is when `r` or `s` is smaller than 32 bytes. This rare, but it can happen. Essentially the rule for encoding these numbers is to encode them as a big endian signed integer but do it as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Andrew. I wasn't aware of DER encoding rules as defined in BIP-66. I have tried to inculcate the rules in my code. Now I am converting high S into low S which solves problem for half of the transaction. However, R encoding is still not working when R as signed integer is positive. Let me show you the example:

`304402203faf4f96f781a8819531c4a78a35e9c4ea3f1f4ef56493d18eff52881cdf43a702206b0f0072964a7819a9c223f38d7fd73c7063423cb49aa480eedc3b284b41c23b01210329d4fec73ecf28f4bcbe7e235c63764e1c7c3ba7f1d90feeea9be1a8a0696498`

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: @CryptoSar How do you put this in a transaction? The signature seems fine to me but maybe you are encoding it incorrectly in the transaction.

Comment: Yes, you are right Andrew. Actually the problem was in the byte just before signatures representing the sig length. I have rectified it and it is working 100% now. Thanks once again.